# build and execute statement dynamically in SQL server

Tags: sql-server

Hello I'm trying to disable all foreign key constraints on a database as I'm loading in some data. As it's part of a monthly job I want to do it dynamically so it can handle any changes. I'm trying to do this without using a cursor or temp table. I have built the statement below but so far this only creates an alter statement whereas I want it to execute the alter statement

```
declare @SQLStatement as nvarchar(4000)
SET @SQLStatement = 'exec (''select ''''alter table prpcref_mjp''''        + ''''.'''' + b.name + ''''.'''' + parent_tbl.name +  '''' NOCHECK CONSTRAINT '''' +  fk.name
from prpcref_mjp.sys.foreign_keys fk
inner join prpcref_mjp.sys.all_objects parent_tbl
    on fk.parent_object_id = parent_tbl.object_id
inner join prpcref_mjp.sys.schemas b
    on fk.schema_id = b.schema_id'')'
EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQLStatement
```

Comment: Are you concerned about how to recreate the foreign key constraints after all of the data has been loaded?

Answer (score 1):

Leave the exec out of the string:

```
 select exec('alter table prpcref_mjp''' + 
'';'.'''' + 
        b.name + ''''.'''' + parent_tbl.name +  
            '''' NOCHECK CONSTRAINT '''' +  fk.name
                from prpcref_mjp.sys.foreign_keys fk
                inner join prpcref_mjp.sys.all_objects parent_tbl
                    on fk.parent_object_id = parent_tbl.object_id
                inner join prpcref_mjp.sys.schemas b
                    on fk.schema_id = b.schema_id')
```

Comment: That just runs the select statement

Comment: @MattP answer updated, there might be some mistakes in the SQL (as i don't have SQL right now) but hopefully you got the idea.

Comment: this is as far as I could get. I can't seem to add a bracket onto the end of the 'exec' statement:
 `declare @SQLStatement as nvarchar(4000)
 SET @SQLStatement = 'select ''exec(''''alter table prpcref_mjp'' + ''.'' + b.name + ''.'' + parent_tbl.name +  '' NOCHECK CONSTRAINT ''+  fk.name   
 from prpcref_mjp.sys.foreign_keys fk   
 inner join prpcref_mjp.sys.all_objects parent_tbl    
 on fk.parent_object_id = parent_tbl.object_id   
 inner join prpcref_mjp.sys.schemas b    
 on fk.schema_id = b.schema_id + '')'''
 exec(@SQLStatement)`

Comment: you need to think about it in a different way, what am trying to do is a normal select statement with `exec`, the result will call exec for every result row.

Comment: thanks, makes sense. I've included 'exec' in the select however this only returns a result set and doesn't execute the alter command 
 `SET @SQLStatement = 'select ''exec(''''alter table prpcref_mjp'' + ''.'' + b.name + ''.'' + parent_tbl.name +  '' NOCHECK CONSTRAINT ''+  fk.name  + '''''')''   
 from prpcref_mjp.sys.foreign_keys fk     
 inner join prpcref_mjp.sys.all_objects parent_tbl       
 on fk.parent_object_id = parent_tbl.object_id     
 inner join prpcref_mjp.sys.schemas b       
 on fk.schema_id = b.schema_id'
 exec(@SQLStatement)`

Comment: @MattP, it have to be a normal `select` which means select is outside the exec, take a look on my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way to approach creating the string that contains all of the DDL statements:

```
declare @SQLStatement nvarchar(4000) = ''
select @SQLStatement += 'ALTER TABLE prpcref_mjp.' + b.name + '.' + parent_tbl.name + ' DROP CONSTRAINT ' + fk.name + ';' + char(13) + char(10)
  from prpcref_mjp.sys.foreign_keys fk
 inner join prpcref_mjp.sys.all_objects parent_tbl
    on fk.parent_object_id = parent_tbl.object_id
 inner join prpcref_mjp.sys.schemas b
    on fk.schema_id = b.schema_id
print @SQLStatement
exec(@SQLStatement)
```

You can add a `where` clause to limit the tables that you're going to modify.  Comment out the `exec()` at the end if you want to see the code before actually running it.

Note that I added `+ char(13) + char(10)` to make the output of the `print` statement easier to read.

Comment: Hey thanks @user212514 that worked a charm. Only issue was that I need to use fully qualified object names in the selects as I'm running it across multiple databases ie. prpcref_mjp.sys.all_objects. I'll provide an answer that reflects this

Answer (score 0):

```
    select @NSQL = 'set @SQLStatement_out = ''''
select @SQLStatement_out += ''ALTER TABLE ' + @dbname + '.'' + b.name + ''.'' + parent_tbl.name + '' NOCHECK CONSTRAINT '' + fk.name + '';'' + char(13) + char(10)
  from ' + @dbname + '.' + 'sys.foreign_keys fk
 inner join ' + @dbname + '.' +'sys.all_objects parent_tbl
    on fk.parent_object_id = parent_tbl.object_id
 inner join ' + @dbname + '.' + 'sys.schemas b
    on fk.schema_id = b.schema_id
    exec(@SQLStatement_out) '

SET @ParmDefinition = N'@SQLStatement_out varchar(max) OUTPUT';

exec sp_executesql @NSQL, @ParmDefinition, @SQLStatement_out=@SQLStatement OUTPUT;

exec(@SQLStatement)
```